# Object constructor error after webpack building

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gruntjs, webpack

I have project which uses CoffeeScript and Mithril. And I build this project by Grunt + Webpack

When web application is loaded, I have error in console in `rpc-factory.js`:

`Uncaught TypeError: MyObj.JSONRpcClient is not a constructor`

**rpc-factory.coffee:**

```
define [
  'jsonrpc'
], () ->

  class MyObj.RpcFactory
    constructor: () ->

    createRpcClient: (url, funcs) ->
      new MyObj.JSONRpcClient(funcs, url + "json")
```

In `jsonrpc.js` script `MyObj` object and `MyObj.JSONRpcClient` are initialized.

**jsonrpc.js:**

```
if ( typeof MyObj == "undefined" ) {
  var  MyObj = {}
}
```

...

```
MyObj.JSONRpcClient = function() {
  var arg_shift = 0,
    req,
    _function,
    methods,
    self,
    name,
    arg0type = (typeof arguments[0]),
    doListMethods = true;
}
```

My guess:

- "Define" doesn't work and `MyObj` object is returned before `jsonrpc` initialization.

Comment: The indentation in the first piece of code doesn't look right.

Comment: How does `rpc-factory.js` know about `Evernote`? Does `jsonrpc.js` or something else make it global?

Comment: @muistooshort code worked before I start to compile code by Webpack.

Comment: @elclanrs Thx! You're right! The reason is that Webpack did local scope for `jsonrpc.js`. I changed `MyObj` on `window.MyObj` and it work.